# Ubuntu 16.04 slow to start and shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, startup

I have noticed that some stop and start processes take in excess of 1 min 30 secs. Is there a way to speed up these processes?

```
pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5943G:~$ systemd-analyze blame
     1min 3.758s console-setup.service
      1min 387ms gpu-manager.service
         59.871s synaptic.service
         52.570s setvtrgb.service
          6.940s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.280s tlp.service
          3.408s dev-sdb1.device
          2.938s upower.service
          2.470s systemd-udev-trigger.service
           821ms ondemand.service
           802ms alsa-restore.service
           395ms ModemManager.service
           379ms accounts-daemon.service
           331ms grub-common.service
           328ms irqbalance.service
           318ms apport.service
           282ms lm-sensors.service
           279ms rsyslog.service
           276ms pppd-dns.service
           272ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           264ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
           257ms avahi-daemon.service
           129ms udisks2.service
           117ms apparmor.service
            84ms NetworkManager.service
            78ms systemd-logind.service
            68ms systemd-journald.service



pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5943G:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 3.980s
└─multi-user.target @1min 3.979s
  └─getty.target @1min 3.979s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 3.979s
      └─system-getty.slice @1min 3.978s
        └─console-setup.service @219ms +1min 3.758s
          └─local-fs.target @217ms
            └─local-fs-pre.target @217ms
              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @208ms +7ms
                └─system.slice @104ms
                  └─-.slice @102ms
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
ACER Aspire 5943G (Radeon HD Mobile Graphcs)

KERNEL: 4.9.0-040900-generic